# Cadastro não está sendo gravado no banco

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ola, estou criando um sistema de login/cadastro para um trabalho da faculdade, como base estou utilizando alguns tutoriais da internet. Consegui desenvolver bem, mas agora travei...
Meu formulário de cadastro não está gravando as informações no banco, não consigo identificar o porque.

**cadastro.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
$u = new Usuario;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <title>Cadastro</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-light">

    <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group corpo-form">
            <h1 class="text-center">CADASTRO</h1>
            <p class="text-center">Complete se cadastro para ter acesso a área restrita.</p>
            <input type="text" name="nome" class="rounded-pill" placeholder="Nome">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="rounded-pill" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="password" name="senha" class="rounded-pill" placeholder="Senha de 6 digitos" maxlength="6">
            <input type="password" name="confirmsenha" class="rounded-pill" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" maxlength="6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill" value="Cadastrar ">
            <a href="index.php" id="alinhameno-link">← Voltar</a>
        </div>

        <?php
//verificar se clicou no botao
if (isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome =  $_POST['nome'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $senha =  $_POST['senha'];
    $confirmsenha = $_POST['confirmsenha'];
    //verificar se as informacoes estao completas
    if(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($senha) && !empty($confirmsenha)){

        $u->conectar("dbi","localhost", "root","");
        if($u->msgErro =="")//sem erros
        {
            if($senha == $confirmsenha){
               if($u->cadastrar($nome, $email, $senha)){
                echo "Cadastrado com sucesso! Faça seu login para entrar.";
               }
               else{
                   echo "E-mail já cadastrado!";
               }
            }
            else{
                echo "As senhas não coincidem";
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro; 
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Preencher todos os campos!";}
    }
    ?>

    </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

**usuarios.php**

```
<?php

class Usuario
{
    private $pdo; 
    public $msgErro = "";//sem erros

    public function conectar( $nome, $host, $usuario, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO ("mysql: dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host,$usuario,$senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();

        }

    }

    public function cadastrar($nome, $email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        //verificar se já existe e-mal cadastrado
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email = :e ");
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            return false; // Já está cadastrado
        }
        //Caso não, cadastrar
        else{
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome,email,senha) VALUES(:n, :e, :s)");
            $sql->bindValue(":n",$nome);
            $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
            $sql->bindValue(":s", md5($senha));
            $sql->execute();
            return true;
        } 

    }

    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        //verificar se email e senha estão cadastrados,se sim
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email =:e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
        $sql->execute();
        if( $sql->rowCount() > 0){
            //entrar no sistema/sessao
            $dado = $sql->apc_fetch();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dado['id_usuario'];
            return true; //login efetuado com sucesso
        }
        else{
            return false;//nao foi possivel logar
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, você faz o POST dos dados do formulário para a mesma página. Apesar da página chamar a sua classe "Usuario", você não está abrindo a conexão com o banco e chamando a função "cadastrar".

Uma das formas de resolver isso seria alterar o código seguinte forma:

```html
<?php
require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
$u = new Usuario;
//Se existir um POST com estes 3 campos...
if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {
 //Abrir conexão e executar função de gravar 
 $u->conectar("nome do banco, "nome do servidor", "usuario banco", "senha banco");
 $u->cadastrar($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Infelizmente continua não gravando no banco, até aparece a confirmação de envio mas o banco continua vazio.